# Job requirements for typing Chinese

Tags: writing, mainland-china, hong-kong, transcription

Many government positions in Taiwan have typing speed requirements.  In Taipei city job announcements I've found which mention this requirement, the minimum runs from 40-60 characters a minute. This is not that far from the US.  [California's state government](https://jobs.ca.gov/job/typingcertification), for example, requires a minimum of 40 words/min.

Do government positions in mainland China have typing speed requirements? If so, what are they? Are inputting methods set, or can you choose your own? Are there official certificates and certification agencies or do have to take a test every time you apply. I haven't been able to find such job announcements so far, so if you have suggestions about finding these I would be especially interested.  If you know about Hong Kong or Singapore, I would be equally interested. Thanks!

Comment: if you search for 公务员打字速度 in baidu, you would get something (in Chinese )

Comment: Actually if you want to apply for a clerk in Hong Kong, there's no limit, you just need to know how to type Chinese then it's OK

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are some things that I found:

http://www.bjshy.gov.cn/Item/64056.aspx:
Beijing Shunyi district in a job related to labor disputes: > 70 WPM.

http://ghj.fuzhou.gov.cn/ghjzwgk/rsxx/201504/t20150414_890668.htm
Fuzhou city/countryside planning: ~60 WPM

http://www.mohrss.gov.cn/SYrlzyhshbzb/fwyd/sykaoshi/zyhgjjgsydwgkzp/201401/W020140124568664734613.doc.
Ministry of Human Resources and Social Security: > 90 WPM for Chinese, > 220 Letters/min for English

http://www.gzjd.gov.cn/jdwsjb/xxgk_phoneweb/xxgkml_phoneweb/tzgg_phoneweb/qt_tzgg_phoneweb/20141104/detail-273178.shtml
Guangzhou Liwan District Public Security Bureau:>50WPM

It seems in general 50 WPM is kinda the minimum. And most places want more. I didn't find any info about certification.

Comment: Great! This is just the kind of stuff I was looking for.  220 letters/min... very odd.  and 90 字/分 is really fast!!

Comment: Yea, I found the 220 letters thing quite strange as well. I'm somewhat curious as to why Chinese standards seem so much higher. Maybe it's the  仓颉 input method because i can't get anywhere close to those WPM (though I'm not a great Chinese typer myself).